# How to obtain ISBN Barcode in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am doing a project on ISBN barcode scanning. I have tried many scanning applications but after scanning this barcode: [image]

the app only gives me back the barcode 9780749423490. 
But what I need to obtain is the ISBN code 0749423498 instead, as it is in the database of my library. Is there any method to get it?

Can anyone explain the difference between these two codes? Why is the barcode number and ISBN barcode number different? Is it the same for some books and different for some ? thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the confusion is the difference between the "ISBN 10" and "ISBN 13" standards.

The ISBN Agency website [FAQ](http://www.isbn.org/standards/home/about/faqs_main.html) says:

```
"Does the ISBN-13 have any meaning imbedded in the numbers? 
The five parts of an ISBN are as follows:

 1. The current ISBN-13 will be prefixed by "978"
 2. Group or country identifier which identifies a national or geographic grouping of publishers
 3. Publisher identifier which identifies a particular publisher within a group
 4. Title identifier which identifies a particular title or edition of a title
 5. Check digit is the single digit at the end of the ISBN which validates the ISBN"
```

So the 978 is clearly just filler. After that, the next 9 numbers are obviously the same in both numbers. The last digit in both numbers is a check digit, which is different in ISBN 10 and ISBN 13. See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_digit#ISBN_10) for details, but the two formulas are:

For ISBN 10 (the top one), the sum of all digits multiplied by mutlipliers 10-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1 mod 11 should be 0:

```
0*10 + 7 *9 + 4*8 + 9*7 + 4*6 + 2*5 + 3*4 + 4*3 + 9*2 + 8*1 % 11 == 0
```

For ISBN 13 (the bottom one) the sum of the odd digits * 1 plus the sum of the even digits * 3 should be 0. This is including the leading 978. (this is similar to the UPC code as "user..." mentioned but a little different as noted in the Wikipedia article):

```
9*1 + 7*3 + 8*1 + 0*3 + 7*1 + 4*3 + 9*1 + 4*3 + 2*1 + 3*3 + 4*1 + 9*3 + 0*1 % 10 == 0
```

So you can get the ISBN 10 code (top) from the ISBN 13 (bottom) code as follows:

```
isbnBaseCode = <9780749423490 from the 4th to 12th characters>

isbn10CheckDigit = 11 - (isbnBaseCode[0]*10 + isbnBaseCode[1]*9 + ... + isbnBaseCode[8]*2) % 11

isbnCode10 = isbnBaseCode + isbn10CheckDigit
```

Comment: Oh I see.. Thanks for the detailed explanation things seems so much clearer now :)

Answer (score 1):

The long and short of your question is that they are in fact both ISBNs.
One is in the 10 digit format and the other is in the newer 13 digit format.

```
978 074942349 0
    074942349 8
```

The 978 is a prefix and the last digit, on both, is a check digit .
The barcode on the item you are scanning only represents the 13 digit format.

According to http://www.isbn.org/standards/home/isbn/transition.asp
You can always convert from 13 digit ISBN starting with 978 to the 10 digit format
and provides a link to an online converter. It also discusses the 979 prefix.
I don't believe the 979 prefix is being used yet but its good to be aware that they may be used in future.

Having worked in the Library apps space, when searching a library catalog
item records will vary greatly in what information they contain.
Item records, specifically regarding ISBN, can contain the 10 digit ISBN, 13 digit ISBN, both, or none. So to find an item you might have to try both formats.
I believe that some systems, if your search type is set to ISBN, will actually check the submitted ISBN and search for both formats automatically.

Depending on what your trying to do.
Many library search functions allow for wild cards which may make it easier to find 
the item your looking for. For example:

```
'if the isbn has a length of 13 and starts with 978 
    remove the first 3 (the 978) and last digit (the check digit)
    add a wildcard character to the front and back
    begin search
end if
```

eg 9780749423490 would become *07494234*
The downside is that it might return multiple results.
Even if that were to happen it would likely only be a couple items and the one your
looking, if there, would be easy to spot.

As provided by others the Wikipedia article on ISBN goes into more technical details on how to convert between the 10 and 13 digit formats.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number

Comment: Thanks for helping and even giving some pointer on how should i write my if statement thanks!!

Comment: do you happen to know any online isbn converter that will pass back xml?:d

Answer (score 0):

The number starting 978 is a product code, specifically a UPC (Universal Product Code), that includes the ISBN but without the check digit at the end. Have a look at [ISBN on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISBN) for code on generating the check digit and you'll be able to reconstruct the ISBN from the UPC.